# Print Gradle's current lifecycle phase

Tags: gradle

I am learning Gradle and understanding at which point various things apply in the build lifecycle seems essential to making the most of Gradle. In order to double check my understanding I'd like to know if there is a way to print which phase the build cycle is in at particular points.

E.g. hypothetically

```
task aTask() {
    println 'Current phase : <call to hypothetical phase reporter>'
    doLast {
        println 'Current phase : <call to hypothetical phase reporter>'
    }
}
```

would then print

```
$ gradle -q aTask
Current phase : configuration
Current phase : execution
```

if I understand the phases correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no such mechanism. What can be useful in indicating the current phase of lifecycle are the following listeners: [BuildListener](http://gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/BuildListener.html), [ProjectEvaluationListener](http://gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/ProjectEvaluationListener.html), [TaskExecutionGraphListener](http://gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/execution/TaskExecutionGraphListener.html) and [TaskExecutionListener](http://gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/execution/TaskExecutionListener.html). `logger` statements may be added in appropriate method to know how the things are going.

Comment: It should be plainly obvious if you use --info   config tasks will be preceeded with "Configure project :" and execution phase preceeded with "Task :"

It is still annoying to no end trying to debug

Comment: It's things like this that make me hate gradle.